# Mouse click on selected item in listbox unselect the others items

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, listbox, mouseclick-event

In `listbox` when several items is selected and I click on one of them, the others become unselected.

How to allow possibility become unchanged the others items?

Comment: Not sure what you need here.. Do you want your listbox to behave like the user always has the CTRL+KEY down? Looks like you want to change the natural behaviour of a windows control... IMHO, you should not do this...

Comment: @Baral Not exactly. Please select several items with ctrl key. And then click on one of them. Then only this item will be selected. I would like to others items also stay selected (until I'm clicking on one of these selected items)

Comment: Say you have 3 items, and you selected all of them with ctrl key. now you realised you actually only want to select the first item, what do you want to do to achieve this with the behaviour you described?

Comment: I think it is a wrong usage of the control.. Can you explain why you need such a feature? Maybe we can suggest something else..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `SelectionMode` to `MultiSimple`.  Note that in this mode it is not necessary to hold down the Ctrl key!